# Release apk crash on launch without any message

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crash, signed-apk

i generated the app-release.apk but the apk file crashes when i launch it from my android device. It installs properly but crashes when launched.

I dont have any problem using the debug apk. I saw a solution saying to replace
View.propTypes to ViewPropTypes but I haven't used it anywhere. Despite that, i imported ViewPropTypes in all my js files. But i cant seem to figure out the issue.

Can somebody help?

Thank you

you can find my code [here](https://github.com/AnitaLama/AnitaLama.github.io/tree/master/wine)

I tried uninstalling my packages. and i can create a working release apk if no other packages are installed.

Comment: Can you please share some code snippet ?

Comment: Also connect your device to pc and open android studio, then launch the app, it will show the crash logs in android log window